# Pass parameter outside of AngularJS directive into HTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is the problem: I want to sort a table by clicking on a table header. To avoid repeating code every , I have made  a directive. The table headers show up nicely but I cannot find a way to make them sortable.
This is (part of) my HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive" >
    <table class="table table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th><t-header name="vnaam" hoofd="voornaam" ></t-header></th>
                <th><t-header name="anaam" hoofd="achternaam"></t-header></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr dir-paginate="cursist in homeCtrl.ckaart | orderBy: homeCtrl.sortKey:!homeCtrl.reverse" current-page="homeCtrl.currentPage">
                <td><a ng-click="homeCtrl.gotoDetail(cursist.id)"><span ng-class="cursist.keuzemotivatie.length || cursist.leerdoelen.length ? 'infosign-true' : 'infosign-false'" class="fa fa-info-circle infosign"></span></a></td>
                <td>{{cursist.vnaam}}</td>
                <td>{{cursist.anaam}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

My directive:

```
.directive('tHeader', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      name: "@",
      hoofd: "@"
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/theader.html',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: function() {
      var vm = this;

      vm.sortKey = '-instrument';
        // sort t.b.v. table sorting

        vm.sort = function(keyname) {
            // alert(keyname);
            vm.sortKey = keyname;
            vm.reverse = !vm.reverse;
        console.log(vm.sortKey);
        }
    }

  }
})
```

And the template belonging to the directive:

```
<div ng-click="vm.sort(vm.name)">{{vm.hoofd}}
  <span ng-show="vm.sortKey === vm.name" ng-class="{ 'fa fa-chevron-up':vm.reverse, 'fa fa-chevron-down':!vm.reverse }"></span>
</div>
```

It seems to me that the 'vm.sortKey' parameter as well as the 'vm.reverse' parameter are not being passed into the HTML.
Anyone an idea? What mistake do I make?

Comment: Works in this [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/rzuWHzZpb99ewYslyQ5N?p=preview). **Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem!** If you inadvertently fixed the problem while composing the example but didn't test it again, you'd want to know that before asking someone else to help.

Comment: @georgeawg Of course, you're totally right. I was convinced the probleem had something to do with the directive. You proved me that I was wrong.

Comment: @georgeawg I updated my HTML with a ng-repeat (i.c. dir-paginate) in which I placed an orderBy expression. I think that this expression fails, but I don't know how to check that. As you can see I use controller-as syntax. Therefor I use 'homeCtrl' to bind to the controller. I also replaced it with 'vm', but that doesn't work either. Sure, I do something wrong, but I just don't see it. I hope you can point me in the right direction.